# How do i set hit event only for child in amcharts force directed graph?

Tags: javascript, nodes, amcharts, amcharts4

I am trying to make the nodes clickable but i want only the child to be clickable and not the parent but i am unable to figure out on how to do it.
I am using amcharts. 
Is there any way to use **Hit** event only for child nodes?

```
networkSeries.nodes.template.events.on("hit", function (event) {

 location.href="https://www.google.com/";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but here goes:

```
networkSeries.nodes.template.events.on("hit", function (event) {
  if (event.target.dataItem.level === 1)
    location.href="https://www.google.com/";
  }
});
```